# Upload Iphone app (.ipa) from mac os x 2.4 (Tiger) or xcode 2.4

Tags: iphone, xcode, sencha-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipa

I have an Iphone app (.ipa) file which I have develop using sencha. I want to upload this on the iphone application store. I have macintosh with os x ver 2.4 (Tiger). Can I use this mac to upload iphone app in the app store using this os? Or is there any way to upload application from my windows laptop (I have already tried virtual machine but mac os lion file is not installing in the vertual machine ).

I am able to install XCode 2.4 on my mac, but i am not getting that how I can use this xcode for uploading app to store.

Any help will be thankful.

Thanks
Ishan jain

Comment: You need Xcode 4.5 or later to do current iOS development. And this requires Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or later. And the oldest version of iOS you can support is iOS 4.3. You must support iOS 6.0 and the full screen of the iPhone 5.

Comment: actually I already developed the app and also tested.Just I need to upload it to store.

Comment: And I'm telling you what Apple requires. Apple will not accept an app that supports iOS 3 or has been created with such an old version of Xcode.